# Jumpers within diode through-holes in a PCB

Tags: pcb, diodes

I'm designing a keypad and I may not need to use diodes so I was thinking to use open jumpers within through-holes.

[image]

In case I need a diode I can still solder it otherwise I can bridge the jumper.

Is this a safe thing to do?

Comment: Safe, but redundant. You can put a 0R resistor (a jumper) on diode pads. Or (just don't ever admit) solder the pads together without any component.

Comment: I'd consider that to be an adequate answer for this.  No reason not to other than that you're giving up board space and don't need to.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum -- make that an answer and I'll give you a +1 for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safe, but redundant. You can put a 0R resistor (a jumper) on diode pads. Or (just don't ever admit) solder the pads together without any component.